# Object in NSMutableArray crushed in memory

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I have some big problem with an `NSMutableArray` I'm filling with objects in a database. I'm using `[appDelegate.myArray addObject:myObject]`, then somehow the object gets crushed in the memory, I don't know why, I didn't release anything.

How that can happen?

Comment: What does "crushed in the memory" mean? Crushed is not a term I'm familiar with in this context.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the array?  Is it perhaps being autoreleased when you don't want it to be? (i.e. did you create with with `+alloc` and `-init` or with `+array` ?

And yes, what on earth does "crushed" mean in this sense? :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to translate the word in french xD. Actually I meant that something was written over my object in the memory, so that I cannot access it again. I'm creating my array with "NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was actually that in my object initialisation method I did something like :

name = @"";
address = @"";
...

instead of :

**self**.name = @"";
**self**.address = @"";
...

Be careful to not waste your time with that kind of mistake...